# Casting string to Z3.expr in .Net API

Tags: c#, z3

I have a string variable which I need to cast into Expr type. I am using the Z3 .Net API. Is this possible?

**Edit**

```
List<Node<string>> lChildren = new List<Node<string>>(); 
//...   
switch (pNode.Data)
{ 
    //...
    case ">=": 
    { 
        lResult = lZ3Solver.GreaterOrEqualOperator(
            lChildren[0].Data, 
            int.Parse(lChildren[1].Data)
        );
```

The first argument of `GreaterOrEqualOperator` is of type `Expr`. In this case I need to cast the current string type to Expr type.

Comment: you need to post the relevant code section

Comment: List<Node<string>> lChildren = new List<Node<string>>();
...
switch (pNode.Data)
{
 ...case ">=":
  {
   lResult = lZ3Solver.GreaterOrEqualOperator(lChildren[0].Data, int.Parse(lChildren[1].Data));
   
The first argument of 'GreaterOrEqualOperator' is of type Expr. In this case I need to cast the current string type to Expr type.

Comment: move comment to OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

A variable (constant function) of name `lChildren[0]` can be created by calling `ctx.MkConst(lChildren[0], sort)`, where `ctx` is a `Context` and `sort` is the sort/type of the variable, e.g., it could be `ctx.IntSort` for integers.

Note that Z3 allows two variables of the same name, i.e., calling `ctx.MkConst` a second time with the same name/sort, will create a new variable, which is different from the first one. If the same variables are required at a time later than their construction time, the need to be saved elsewhere, e.g., in a hashtable (or Dictionary) that allows for quick lookups.